# Challenge : Best way to check if model object array contains properties of model in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, enumeration

Model  = CountryCode

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * abbreviation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
```

Model array = CountryCodesArray

Problem:
I have countrycode for eg: 81

I want to check if 81 is in my model array or not ??

Query: 
I want to make the process efficient.
I dont' want to check in for in loop like as :

```
for (CountryCode * countcode in Countrycodes) {
        NSLog(@"\n%@", countcode.code);
}
```

Tried fast enumeration , but crashed , any suggestions ??

```
BOOL isCodePresent = [[Countrycodes valueForKeyPath:@"CountryCode.code"] containsObject:@"81"];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use "code" instead of "CountryCode.code" as key in fast enumeration..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without doing a loop you can use the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate`

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code == 81"];
NSArray *filtered = [countryCodesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Then if you need the object:

```
CountryCode *countcode = (CountryCode*)[filtered objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: filtered array no values

Comment: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code == 81"]; works 
but

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code == %d",variable]; not ??